# Problemas al exportar e importar

Tags: javascript, importación, exportar

No se por que me da esta dando problemas, intento hacer un export en un js del front a otro js del front pero no consigo que funcione....

Este código lo ubico dentro mi front.js

```js
export default function () { console.log("Nice job") }
```

este lo ubico dentro de mi frontCancelar.js

```js
import myFunc from './frontUFro';
myFunc();
```

Este es el error que me lanza
[image: El error]

Hantes he puesto fotos para que vierais un poco el contexto que pienso que es mas interesante que solo el código pero.... parece que no es correcto

Comment: Primero edita tu pregunta y en lugar de fotos, pon tu codigo en texto, para que al resto nos sea mas fácil probarlo. Segundo ten en cuenta que solo puedes exportar una función tipo default por archivo, no se si es tu caso

Comment: @susu ya esta el código, no tengo mas exportaciones nisiquiera es esta que quiero hacer pero la he escrito para ver si me funciona pero no parece hacerlo, mi idea es exportar una variable con unas coordenadas

Comment: Ese código está bien, debería funciónar siempre y cuando estén bien las rutas en la importación. De todas maneras, creo que ese error es de otra cosa, la verdad es que si solo tienes esas lineas en los archivos no debería haber problema. Antes en las fotos he visto que tenías mas lineas de código, prueba a comentarlas todas y que solo haya estas y debería funcionar

Comment: si la función la ubicas en tu front.js como dijiste, la importación la haces de fronUFro

Comment: Bueno al final lo he resuelto utilizando cookies, gracias de todas formas